# Anyone know why these if else statement wont work?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public class Salary
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        double currentSalary; // employee's current salary
        double raise; // amount of the raise
        double percentRaise;   // percentage of the raise
        double newSalary; // new salary for the employee
        String rating; // performance rating

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print ("Enter the current salary: ");
        currentSalary = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.print ("Enter the performance rating (Excellent, Good, or Poor): ");
        rating = scan.next();
        if (rating.equals("Excellent"))

            percentRaise = .06;   
            raise = (.06 * currentSalary);


            else if (rating.equals("Good"))

                    percentRaise = .04;
                   raise = (.04 * currentSalary); 


                   else  if (rating.equals("Poor"))

                       percentRaise = .015;
                       raise = (.015 * currentSalary);

        //Compute the raise using if ...

        newSalary = currentSalary + raise;

        //Print the results
        NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Current Salary: " + money.format(currentSalary));
        System.out.println("Amount of your raise: " + money.format(raise));
        System.out.println( "Your new salary: " + money. format (newSalary) );
        System.out.println();
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

if i add { and } where the whitespace is then it says raise is not initialized. No matter what i do i cant seem to figure out to get it running.  Right now it tells me to delete the else to let it run but if i do no matter i write excellent, good, or poor. It does .015 * salary so i cant get excellent or good to run.

Comment: Wrap your code in braces `{}`. This has nothing to do with Eclipse. Read about variable scope.

Comment: if i do this         if (rating.equals("Excellent"))
        {
            percentRaise = .06;   
            raise = (.06 * currentSalary);
        
        }   
            else if (rating.equals("Good"))
            {
                    percentRaise = .04;
                   raise = (.04 * currentSalary); 
                
            }  
                   else  if (rating.equals("Poor"))
                   {
                       percentRaise = .015;
                       raise = (.015 * currentSalary);
                   }

Comment: then i cant initialize raise

Comment: Don't post code in comments. You have to **make sure**  it's initialized in all execution paths.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (rating.equals("Excellent"))
    percentRaise = .06;   
    raise = (.06 * currentSalary);
else if (rating.equals("Good"))
```

Won't compile because Java sees this as...

```
if (rating.equals("Excellent"))
    percentRaise = .06;   

raise = (.06 * currentSalary);

else if (rating.equals("Good"))
```

Meaning that the compiler will complain about the `else-if` without a `if` statement.

The other problem you're having (when you place `{ }` around the statements) is because Java makes no determination about what the initial value of a local variable will have.

This means Java simply doesn't know what to do with `newSalary = currentSalary + raise;` as there is no guarantee that `raise` will have a value assigned to it.

You could overcome this by adding an `else` condition to the end of your `if-else` block or simply supplying an initial value to your local variables...

```
    double currentSalary = 0; // employee's current salary
    double raise = 0; // amount of the raise
    double percentRaise = 0;   // percentage of the raise
    double newSalary = 0; // new salary for the employee
    String rating = ""; // performance rating
```

And while it might seem annoying, it's better then getting some completely random value which you would have to spend time trying to debug ;)

**Updated**

Remember, `String#equals` is case sensitive, this means "Excellent" is not equal to "excellent".

You could use `String#equalsIgnoreCase` instead

Comment: if i initialize everything then it runs but the answer is always 0

Comment: Remember, `equals` is case sensitive, so if you enter "excellent" then  it will no match any of your `if` statements.  You could try using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead.  I did run your (corrected code) and it works fine for me...so long as I enter the correct value

Comment: I ran it as well and it works. Though @MadProgrammer I noticed your `String rating = 0;` is a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that if your if statement contains more than one line of code, it is wrapped in braces.

```
public class Salary
 {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    double currentSalary; // employee's current salary
    double raise; // amount of the raise
    double percentRaise;   // percentage of the raise
    double newSalary; // new salary for the employee
    String rating; // performance rating

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print ("Enter the current salary: ");
    currentSalary = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.print ("Enter the performance rating (Excellent, Good, or Poor): ");
    rating = scan.next();
    if (rating.equals("Excellent"))
         {
        percentRaise = .06;   
        raise = (.06 * currentSalary);

         }
        else if (rating.equals("Good"))
        {
                percentRaise = .04;
               raise = (.04 * currentSalary); 

          }
               else  if (rating.equals("Poor"))
       {
                   percentRaise = .015;
                   raise = (.015 * currentSalary);
          }
    //Compute the raise using if ...

    newSalary = currentSalary + raise;

    //Print the results
    NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Current Salary: " + money.format(currentSalary));
    System.out.println("Amount of your raise: " + money.format(raise));
    System.out.println( "Your new salary: " + money. format (newSalary) );
    System.out.println();
    scan.close();
}
```

}

Comment: And the purpose of this block of code isn't clear. Please add a description explaining what it is that you've changed.

Comment: not sure what do you mean by OP but raise is declared as a class level variable and should be able to access it. if the compiler throws a not initialised then i guess we can initialise with a default value, something like 0.0? should be piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap if statements into these things ---> "{}"

so its like this:

```
if(statement){
   //then do someting
}else{
   //then do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only write if statements without braces if it contains only one command, if you have more than one command (more than one line) you need to enclose those commands in braces